# Where is the best place to acquire large amounts of testnet eth?

Tags: ether, ropsten, testnets, rinkeby

While there are fairly easy ways to get small amounts of testnet ETH (e.g., 1 ETH) through faucets. What would be the best way to get a larger amount of testnet ETH (10-1000) in a time-sensitive way?

Answer (score 3):

The [Chainstack Faucet](https://faucet.chainstack.com/) distributes test tokens for the major Ethereum networks and more.

You can get tokens for:

- [Ethereum Sepolia](https://faucet.chainstack.com/sepolia-faucet) — Use it to test DApps and smart contracts
- [Ethereum Goerli](https://faucet.chainstack.com/goerli-faucet) — Use it to test Validators and staking
- [Ethereum Holesky](https://faucet.chainstack.com/holesky-faucet) — Use it to test Validators and staking
- [BNB Smart](https://faucet.chainstack.com/bnb-testnet-faucet) Chain testnet
- [zkSync](https://faucet.chainstack.com/zksync-testnet-faucet) testnet
- [Scroll](https://faucet.chainstack.com/scroll-sepolia-testnet-faucet) testnet

Feel free to reach out if you need a relatively high amount of test tokens; I'll try to find them!

Full disclosure: I'm a developer advocate at Chainstack and worked on this faucet.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get a large amount of ether from faucets. I usually get max of 5 ether at once.

Comment: This is the context of the question:

"While there are fairly easy ways to get small amounts of testnet ETH (e.g., 1 ETH) through faucets..."

Just to clarify, I'm not asking how to get ETH from faucets, I'm asking what's the best way to get a large number of testnet eth quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to select the third option on the **Give me Ether** drop down button at https://faucet.rinkeby.io/, which gives you 18.75 Ethers. Though, you'll have to wait for maximum of 3 days.

Comment: Hi Jemil, appreciate this, but unfortunately it is still a faucet based answer I'm afraid. Rinkeby has the most generous faucet by far.

Comment: I see what you mean. You are right, Rinkeby has the most the most generous, they gave me the 18,75 Ethers within few hours yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

https://faucets.chain.link/
You can get 0.1 eth every 24 hours

Answer (score 0):

There's this page I found https://www.ropsten.money/l/ropsten where you can buy 10 rETH on ropsten for around 6$.
There might be similar pages to this for other networks.

I haven't used the page yet, so I would suggest that you make your own research on its legitimacy.